# MPAndroidChart moveViewToX not always working

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm implementing a paging solution and load data when I reach the left side of the graph (using setOnChartGestureListener), the data is displayed in reverse order (with negative x values). After loading the new set of data the viewport should jump to the first loaded entry, but the method moveViewToX is giving sometimes erratic behavior and will not move the viewport.

I’ve tried different hacks, like a delayed moveViewToX, calling moveViewToX from other places, even adding a button to the activity calling moveViewToX is not working.

I searched stackoverflow and found a similar problem related to moveViewToX but didn’t solve the problem ([HorizontalBarChart moveViewToX doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270146/horizontalbarchart-moveviewtox-doesnt-work)).

I’m using this version of MPAndroidChart

```
com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0
```

I reduced the code to a minimum in order to reproduce the behavior.

activity_device_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_5">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ChartTestActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.ChartTouchListener;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartGestureListener;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.EntryXComparator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import es.arpa.sensor.iot.R;

public class ChartTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String TAG = ChartTestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int ENTRIES_PER_PAGE = 100;

    private LineChart mChart;
    private int mPageCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_graph);
        mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        initChart();

        getData(mPageCount);
    }

    private void initChart() {

        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        mChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
        mChart.setExtraBottomOffset(20);

        // X-Axis Style
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        // Y-Axis Style
        YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxis.enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
        yAxis.setAxisMaximum(20);
        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        // Create a dataset
        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(values, "TEST");
        set.setLineWidth(3f);
        set.setColor(getColor(R.color.purple_200));
        set.setDrawCircles(false);

        // Hide data point values
        set.setDrawValues(false);

        // Selection indicator
        set.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
        set.setHighlightLineWidth(1f);

        // Customize legend entry
        set.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
        set.setFormLineWidth(3f);
        set.setFormSize(30.f);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set);

        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        mChart.setData(data);

        mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
                if (mChart.getLowestVisibleX() == mChart.getXAxis().getAxisMinimum())
                    getData(mPageCount++);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getData(int page) {
        LoadDataAsyncTask task = new LoadDataAsyncTask(new LoadDataListener<List<Entry>>() {
            @Override
            public void taskFinished(List<Entry> result) {
                ListIterator it = result.listIterator();
                LineDataSet set = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
                Entry jumpTo = null;
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Entry entry = (Entry) it.next();
                    set.addEntry(entry);
                    if (jumpTo == null)
                        jumpTo = entry;
                }

                Collections.sort(set.getValues(), new EntryXComparator());

                set.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
                mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mChart.invalidate();

                mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(50);
                mChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(10);

                // This statement should jump at the beginning of the added entries
                mChart.moveViewToX(jumpTo.getX());
            }

        });
        task.execute(page);
    }

    public interface LoadDataListener<T> {
        void taskFinished(T result);
    }

    public class LoadDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Entry>> {

        private LoadDataListener mListener;

        public LoadDataAsyncTask(LoadDataListener loadDataListener) {
            mListener = loadDataListener;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Entry> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            List<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
            int page = params[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < ENTRIES_PER_PAGE; i++) {
                int xValue = -(i + (page * ENTRIES_PER_PAGE));
                int yValue = page;
                values.add(new Entry(xValue, yValue));
            }
            return values;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Entry> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.taskFinished(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Has this been solved? Experiencing a similar issue and cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Reliable working solution which doesn't permanently disable flinging:

1. disable drag deceleration and dispatch a touch event (to cancel possible existing flings):

   isDragDecelerationEnabled = false
   dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
   SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0f, 0f, 0))
2. set data, etc.
3. move the view and schedule a job to re-enable drag deceleration

   moveViewToX(10f)
   postDelayed({ isDragDecelerationEnabled = true}, 100L)

This makes sure the drag deceleration runs after the job to move the view finishes.

When using the animated version (moveViewToAnimated) the delay needs to be adjusted accordingly.

The solution is not the most elegant, as working with scheduled jobs is never 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you use chart.isDragDecelerationEnabled = false it may work, but you'll lose the smooth scroll animation

Answer (score 0):

moveViewToX will not baypass the X axis maximum. i mean that if you move the view to 100f when the x axis maximum is 50 it will just move to the maximum. so i solved that by specifying manually the x axis maximum and the maximum visible x range. take alook at this code and try to understand it the you can modify it as you need.

```
    LineData plot = temperatureChart.getData();
    temperatureChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(plot.getXMax() + 10f);
    temperatureChart.moveViewToX();

    temperatureChart.notifyDataSetChanged(plot.getXMax()+10f);

    if(temperatureChart.getVisibleXRange()!=20) {
        temperatureChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20f);
    }
```